# Flutter, how to make simple screenshot share?

Tags: flutter

I search for a simple solution to share a screenshot of social media in flutter.

I found this package  ( https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot_share_image ) but it's not intuitive, when I press the button to take a screenshot, I have a full screen of the screenshot in another page, but to understand that it's another page, you have to click on the screen to display the sharing icon... I search a simple way just click on the button to open a dialog to share with a social account.